# Wald Test Statistic

Tags: statistics

I am trying to understand the Wald test statistic as explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test .

What I do not understand is the parameter R in the test statistic: 
**H0: R*theta = r**

[image: Screenshot]

I understand that theta is our vector of parameter estimates, and r the fixed value we want to test against (usually zero).

**But what is R?**

(So far I've seen R being described as matrix and / or restriction function - however I am not able to interpret this explanation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is the matrix with restrictions. For example, the tests
\begin{align*}
\beta_1 - 2\beta &= 3 \\
\beta_3 - \beta_4 &= 0 \\
\beta_2 + 3\beta_4 &= 1
\end{align*}
can be represented as
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{R}\vec{\mathbf{\beta}}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1 \\
\beta_2 \\
\beta_3 \\
\beta_4
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
=r
\end{equation}

Comment: I just read elsewhere: "...the null hypothesis restricts some elements in the parameters vector theta to equal a set of given values (while the others will be ML estimated given this restriction)". This now makes sense, and your example is a helpful one. Thanks

Comment: @user3641140 For a reference, the book Statistical Inference based on the likelihood by A. Azzalini is a very good one.